# Does a detached std::thread need to be deleted after it terminates?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I create a `new` std::thread object, and then `detach()` it. The thread runs for an arbitrary amount of time, and then terminates itself. Since I created the object with `new`, do I need to `delete` it at some point to free up its resources? Or does the thread effectively `delete` itself upon termination?

If it does effectively `delete` itself, will something bad happen if I explicitly `delete` it after it has terminated?

Comment: Be careful, you're using the word "it" and sometimes it's hard to tell if you mean the thread itself or the std::thread object.

Comment: A good way to launch a detached `thread`:  `std::thread(f, a0, a1, ...).detach();`  No need to new it.  No need to delete it.  No chance of forgetting to `detach()` it.  No chance of an exception getting thrown between your construction and the point of detach.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz not sure I understand - why are a thread and a std::thread object different things?

Comment: @StuartBarth A thread is an execution vehicle that may or may not have a corresponding std::thread object. A std::thread object is an instance of a C++ class that may or may not have a corresponding thread. For example, you say "does the thread effectively delete itself upon termination". What does that mean? Are you asking if the thread deletes the std::thread object when the thread terminates? Clearly it can't, since that would cause a disaster if the thread that constructed the std::thread accessed the object if the thread terminated. So is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to `delete` it by yourself.

Once you called [std::thread::detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach), the thread will be separated from the thread object and allowed execution to continue independently, and then the thread object will no longer owns any thread. So the thread won't and impossible to `delete` it upon termination.

Comment: I do not understand this `So the thread won't and impossible to delete it upon termination.`. Do you mean `The thread will not be deleted after terminating its execution 
and ...` What is impossible to delete upon termination? You mean I cannot delete the thread after it terminates? How can I know when the thread was terminated? How could I program the thread to delete itself after it terminates?

Comment: Can I program the thread to delete itself after it terminates by not creating the thread with `new`, then, I can just call `std::thread(...).detach()` and the thread will be automatically deallocated upon its termination? (as the documentation says: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach `Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.`)

Comment: @user I meant to `delete` the thread object. e.g. for `std::thread * t = new std::thread(...); t->detach();`, then you have to write `delete t;` manually. The thread being separated and executed from the thread object can't do that.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, after calling `std::thread * t = new std::thread(...); t->detach();` I can just delete the thread with `delete t;` even if the thread still running, because the thread is now out of my application control, but with the Operating System handling its resources allocations/deallocations, until the thread exits and it is completely deleted by the Operating System.

Comment: So if you create a thread with local scope by just saying std::thread t = std:thread(...);, and then detach it, when the function exits, t will be deleted, but the detached thread will proceed just fine, right? As long as there are no local scope captures..

Comment: @Shavais Yes. This is exactly [the example from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach#Example) shows.

Answer (score 2):

**Every** object in C++ allocated using `new` must be released using `delete`.

Thread is an object "located within OS" (usually). It is created using `std::thread` constructor and released with `detach()`.

Object of class `std::thread` is a С++-object, associated with the thread.

So you have to release both - OS-object and C++-object.

---

Upd. When you create thread, OS allocates internal structures within [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_space) to control it. There are set of properties associated with each thread like state (running, pending, waiting resource), priority, return code, etc.

Comment: Thanks -- can you elaborate on what a "located within OS" thread object is? I'm guessing it's related to @DavidSchwartz's comment?

Comment: @Stuart Barth Updated the answer